# Markov Chain Application - flipping coin heads, tails, finished

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process

> Suppose that we are flipping coins iteratively, until we get tails two
>   in a row. Define three states: Heads, Tails, and Finished. Suppose
>   that the probability of getting a head is $p$, and probability of
>   getting a tail is $(1-p)$.
>
> Required: **(i)**
>   Find the Stochastic Matrix $M$ that models this situation. Define the
>   column as the state you are in currently, and the rows as the state
>   you might transitioning to; **(ii)** Find the probability that you finish before the $4$th flip, assuming that the first flip is a head.

For the first question, am I getting it right?
$$M=\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} p & p & 0 \\(1-p) & 0 & 0 \\0 & (1-p) & 1 \end{bmatrix} \end{align}$$

I have no idea how to do the second question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) I would transpose the matrix you have. Having all rows adding to $1$ is the standard format for stochastic matrices as far as I'm aware.

EDIT: As noted below by Ian, if you're coming from a linear algebra standpoint, your matrix is fine as it is.

(ii) Finishing before the 4th flip assuming the first is a head just means flips $2$ and $3$ must be tails, which has probability $(1-p)^2$ and doesn't need Markov Chains to solve. So the question seems odd in the context of Markov Chains - are you sure you have written it correctly?

Anyway, using the Markov Chain method, the required probability is that of moving from State $0$ to State $2$ in at most $2$ steps (the given assumption puts us in State $0$ after the first
 step). Since State $2$ is an absorbing state, this means we need $p_{02}^{(2)}$ and this value will appear in matrix $M^2$, and it is $(1-p)^2$ as given above.

Comment: I have seen authors use the column stochastic convention, especially if the "overall" context is linear algebra rather than probability. That said, the row stochastic convention seems to be more common. If one is sticking with probability I would argue that the row stochastic convention is superior because it is so much more convenient in continuous time+continuous space problems.

Comment: @Ian Oh, OK. Perhaps Joshua follows that too then. I've never seen it done that way though.

Comment: If you're interested to find an example of usage, I just checked in Strang's Linear Algebra and it is there. You can check the index under "Markov matrix" (in my copy it was 257-258).

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing this out. I don't have Strang, but I've checked Fraleigh's "Linear Algebra" and it has the same as Strang. I've only really studied MCs from the probability-theory angle.